# Copy to Clipboard for Larvel Orchid Column

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, clipboard.js, orchid

I have a question if someone else was in this kind of situation maybe they have a solution,
for Laravel Orchid im trying to make a Copy to Clipboard Button for the Column Name with the clipboard.js. I didn't get how to use it with Laravel Orchid for other Projects it was okay.

my layout looks like this :

```
...
protected function columns(): array
    {
        return [
            TD::make('name', 'Name')
                ->render(function ($item) {
                    return
                        Group::make([
                            Link::make($item->name)->route('platform.item.show', $item),
                            Button::make('myBtn')->id('#myBtn')
                        ]);
                })->sort(),
    ....
```

but with the click on the button im getting only an error:

```
TypeError
Argument 1 passed to Orchid\Screen\Screen::callMethod() must be of the type string, null given, called in /Volumes/T5/www/inventory-manager-laravel/vendor/orchid/platform/src/Screen/Screen.php on line 179
```

what i want is i have in my script.js a function which listening to this id and using then the clipboard js, is there a better way for achieving my goal what am i doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

[Jaba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11840717/jaba), as far as I understand, the button must have a method

`Button::make('myBtn')->id('#myBtn')->method('foo')`.
[Doc](https://orchid.software/en/docs/field/#buttonlink)

> method('methodName') – when clicked, the form will be sent to the specified method within the current screen

So, you could use `Link::make('myBtn')->id('#myBtn')` and style it with `->class('foo-class')`. Total: `Link::make('myBtn')->class('btn btn-primary')->id('#myBtn')`;

Comment: This was a good tip thanks Multi_Pony, i was able to add and trigger my JS, but i  could not solve my issue, the JS was not loading always and only for the 1st element im still researching when i find a solution i will answer myself for some future developers.

Comment: @Jaba, show me your js, maybe I can help you

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure a good way out, for now I came up with a quick and dirty solution which is fine for now, but not the way it should be :

```
TD::make( 'name', 'Name')
    ->render(function ($item) {
        return Group::make([
            $item->name,
            Link::make()
                ->route('platform.item.show', $item)
                    ->icon('action-redo')
                         ->id('myBtn')
                              ->type(Color::INFO()),
                        ])->autoWidth();
                    }),
```

I'm returning the name as string so the user can copy it and add a button to go to the actual page itself.

For what I try to get the actual copy to clipboard is:

I added in the same class following (*I couldn't copy my code without loosing the formatting sorry for the image*)

[image]

and in the column I build it like this :

```
    TD::make( 'name', 'Name')
                ->render(function ($item) {
                    $value = $item->name;
                    $button = '<button id="myBtn" class="btn btn-secondary" data-clipboard-text="'.$value.'">Copy</button>';
                    return Group::make([
                        $button,
                        $item->name,
                    ])->autoWidth();
                }),
```

I also try now to get the clipboard.js with cdn instead of installing it with no success

The second method was with jQuery like Multi_Pony suggested but only the 1st element is seen and working with this :

```
$("#myBtn").click(function(){
    alert("The paragraph was clicked.");
});
```